# getopt to push user to input mandatory arguments

Tags: bash, getopt

I wrote a general getopt case switch before modifying the original script which runs based on simple arguments $1 $2 $3 etc, but not sure of the part to have getopt push a user to have mandatory flags/arguments.

Main portion of the code, to show you:

```
usage()
{
    echo -e "\nMandatory Usage: $0 -d|--domain hello.com -t|--to to@test.com\n";
    echo -e "If you want to put valid FROM address instead of sending from root@$(hostname), usage is:\n\t $0 -d|--domain hello.com -f|--from from@test.com -t|--to to@test.com\n";
}

options=$(getopt -o d:f:t: -l domain:,from:,to: -- "$@")
[ $? -eq 0 ] || {
    echo "Incorrect options provided";
    usage;
    exit 1;
}
eval set -- "$options"
while true; do
    case "$1" in
    -d|--domain)
        DOMAIN=$2;
        shift
        ;;
    -f|--from)
        FROM=$2;
        shift
        ;;
    -t|--to)
        TO=$2;
        shift
        ;;
    --)
        shift
        break
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid options!!";
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done

echo "Domain is $DOMAIN"
echo "From address is $FROM"
echo "To address is $TO"
exit 0;
```

How to make these two flags -d and -t mandatory and -f as optional which takes default value if empty:

To be precise:

Mandatory flag usage should be: ((-f should not be mandatory and if not specified, takes a default value for it))

```
getopt_check -d hello.com -t to@test.com
```

Also should throw an error if the user runs the script simply without any arguments, like `bash getopt_check` without providing any flags.

Also, it should throw an error when the user runs it like as follows, because of the mandatory flag -t missing:

```
getopt_check -d hello.com
```

Sincere apologies if this question has a triviality in it. I never used to getopt usage before and using it the first time and struggling a bit to get my first script worked successfully. I have been referring to many URLs and online guides but failed to solve my particular requirement with it.

Comment: Do you use getopt or getopts?

Comment: getopt as it process long arguments.